# How can I aviod rebuilding WebLogic domain after PTools upgrade?

Tags: peoplesoft

When I upgrade PTools, it forces we to create a new WebLogic domain. I would like to avoid this and have it upgrade the existing WebLogic domain instead. Has anyone else tried this before ?

Answer (score 0):

With a higher version of PeopleTools it is possible that a higher version of Weblogic is required. With the new Weblogic installation, you need to recreate the domains:
PeopleTools 8.53 with Weblogic 10
PeopleTools 8.55 with Weblogic 12

Check Oracle support to see for which Weblogic version your new version of PeopleSoft is certified, it's possible you don't need to install new software (example from 8.52 to 8.53)

Comment: We are already on WebLogic 12c. But we are requested to frequently upgrade PTools. Recently we upgraded from 8.55.05 to 8.55.09. Up next would be 8.55.1x

Comment: I would only patch PTools if you need a certain bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

Within PSADMIN there is an option "7. Refresh Config Home".  If your Weblogic domains are setup within the PS_CFG_HOME directory and managed through PSADMIN then this should redeploy your Weblogic domains with the same settings.

In my limited testing it seemed to work fine with a minor tools patch, such as 8.55.09 to 8.55.12.  If I recall correctly it retained customizations in certain files, such as configuration.properties, and kept my custom files, but certain other files still had to have settings reapplied, like maybe integrationGateway.properties.

That said, I don't believe this is an approved method so you would probably want to thoroughly test in your own environment.  I believe a full rebuild of Weblogic, even for minor patches, is still the recommendation.  Additionally, I definitely would not try this for a major upgrade, such as 8.55 to 8.56.